# Angular 2 - Add file with Functions

Tags: angular

How do I add a file only with functions that i will use several times in the **angular js 2** ?

The created file has to be in **ts** or may be in **js**?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a service class and inject it into the components that will use it's functions.

Angular has a great tutorial on implementing services:

[Angular Service Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, hadn't thought in this form